# (Meteor + YT API v3) Getting video data

Tags: javascript, meteor, youtube, youtube-api

I've been trying to get a videos information on meteor.

From everything I've read up on and tried, I've come to the conclusion that it's best to do it on server, which means I have to use the `renaldo:youtube-api` package.

My question is, how do I go about using it? From what I understand by reading it's atmosphere page, I should be looking at http://ionizabicau.github.io/youtube-api/, however, that page seems to be 404'd.

Where do I refer to for a tutorial? I'm a pretty big noob.
Also, on the atmosphere page it's described how to set it up with

```
YoutubeApi.authenticate({
    type: 'key',
    key: 'YOUR_KEY'
});

Meteor.methods({
    searchVideo: function(search) {
        YoutubeApi.search.list({
            part: "id",
            type: "video",
            maxResults: 5,
            q: search,
        }, function (err, data) {
            console.log(err, data);
        });
    }
});
```

However, from looking at this, I understand it's meant to return search results, not a videos data.

I am trying to return these results --

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=notputtingmyapikeyhere&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description),contentDetails(duration))&part=snippet,contentDetails

```
{
"items": [
{
"id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
"snippet": {
"title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
"description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0."
},
"contentDetails": {
"duration": "PT15M51S"
}

}
]
}
```

Sorry if I am missing something extremely simple and thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, was very simple, had to add https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http and simply do `HTTP.get("videourl")`